# Draw a line between ListViewItem of two ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm-light

in a WPF project with MVVM Light, i have a XAML view that contains two **ListView**. ListViewItems for theses two ListViews are generated by binding to List.

```
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding Collection1} ... />
<ListView ItemsSource={Binding Collection2} ... />
```

My question is : how, by clicking once to an item in a ListView then click to another item in the other ListView, i can draw a line between them ?[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

Comment: I believe it can be done via `AdornerLayer`. On first click save point coordinates in `firstPoint` variable, on second click save point coordinates to `secondPoint`. Then create `Adorner` with constructor that takes these two points and draw line in `OnRender` method. Instantiate this adorner after second click and add it to adorner layer of root window's panel.

Comment: Ok, i will investigate on this solution.